# Importing 40 gb mysql file via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dump

I have a 40 GB MySQL dump file. Can anyone give me the idea how to import the file via phpmyadmin?

Comment: Don't. There's clearly a difference of opinion about the scale of your operations between whoever only allows you access via PHPmyAdmin and your business requirements (requiring 40GB of data).

Comment: I'd say don't even try. Load it from the database server, not over a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to restore it with PHPmyadmin you have to split the files into little chunks, because PHP will block too large files, depending on the serverconfig.

1. Dump just the structure of your tables
2. Import them
3. Dump the data of your tables into a csv
4. split the csv (on windows you can do this with gsplit for example and on unix with the split command
5. Import the little chunks of data

But in general i'll recommend the commandline or contact your ISP

Answer (score 1):

You better use a program like Sequel Pro or MySQL Workbench to import data if you don't have terminal access.

If you have terminal access use:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do large restore with phpmyadmin, PHP will block you, you will have something like "Allowed memory size" after few megs loaded...

Max.

Comment: It depends - if I run my server, I can change the PHP settings as I wish, and even very big files could be uploaded that way.  I don't say phpmyadmin will digest it, so I basically agree with 'don't do it'

Comment: Sure, but if you have access on your servers, use the mysql client instead.